# Reqular expression of 7 digits numbers with optional special characters in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I need validate a 7 digit number with optional dash in between.

I was able to get if I use below.

```
^(\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d)$
```

Is there a way to shorten that?

I tried `^(\d+(-?){7})$` but it's not working.

```
Valid 123-09-23
Valid 12-3092-3
Valid 1-230-9-23
Valid 1234567

Invalid -1237883
Invalid 12345678
InValid 123-45-678
```

PS: I will be implementing this in my Javascript application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a digit and repeat `-?\d` six times:

```
^\d(-?\d){6}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/oTSqri/1

Comment: It's not obvious that we're matching 7 digits

Answer (score 3):

Repeat the *group only* (7 times, so you get 7 digits total), and don't repeat the `\d` as well (else you may match more digits than desired):

```
^(?:\d-?){7}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/yLQHWW/1

(Your original pattern is equivalent to: "Match one or more digits, optionally followed by up to 7 `-` characters".)

Comment: How about `1234567-`?

Comment: not given in example but surely must not end with -, as the question says `in between`

Comment: I got the idea now, to solve `1234567-` can use `^(?:-?\d){7}$`